# How to pick up 2 parameters using scipy optimize

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have data

```
diff_time
0
124
56
87
40
168
449
13
```

I should write a function, where I can get 2 parameters automatically `a and b`, where

```
for el in df['diff_time']:
    if el > a:
        el = b
    else:
        el = continue
```

How can I solve this task? Is it real to do using [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) by `boolean mask` created by `df.diff_time > a`:

```
a = 100
b = 33

print (df.diff_time > a)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7    False
Name: diff_time, dtype: bool

df['b'] = df.diff_time.mask(df.diff_time > a, b)
print (df)
   diff_time   b
0          0   0
1        124  33
2         56  56
3         87  87
4         40  40
5        168  33
6        449  33
7         13  13
```

If you need change column `diff_time` use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
df.ix[df['diff_time']>= a ,'diff_time'] = b
print (df)
   diff_time
0          0
1         33
2         56
3         87
4         40
5         33
6         33
7         13
```

Comment: Can you explain, what you do there?

Comment: Sorry, it was wrong, because I think `b = el`, not `el = b`

Comment: Sorry, I check it bad first, but now  think it can works nice.

Comment: Why a = 100 and b = 33?

Comment: this is some constant, I think it is numbers.

Comment: I should write algorithm, where I don't pick up `a` and `b`. It should determine automatically

Comment: Yes, maybe you can better explain it - what is desired output in this sample `dataframe` and why?

Comment: This data - is research of user internet session `df.date.diff().dt.total_seconds()
print df1`. It's interval in seconds between session. I have a problem - I don't know duration of every session and I should find it. I need it function, that would be takes `a` and `b` and it function would be determine better value for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115737/discussion-between-jezrael-and-arseniy-krupenin).

Comment: I mean, if`el > a` session is over and it's assigned a value `b`. If `el < a`, session isn't over and algorithm should `continue`

Comment: Can you say, why did you choose `a = 100` and `b = 33`?

Comment: It was only random constants - I think you need count output by some constants - so I choose 100 and 33. Btw, do you get some progress with scipy?

Comment: unfortunately, no progress

Comment: In your skin I  will describe problem much more, create some test data, add desired output, add some code and ask `scipy` community how to get desired output. (I think tag numpy and scipy are good choice.) Because without output is it very difficult help you.

Comment: I'm thinking how explain it better. I should write function, that can automatically determine 2 parameters `a` and `b` based on column with data. And next I should minimize this function `f(a, b) -> [x, y]`, where `x = 35.2, y = 1.6`. How explain it better?

Comment: ok, but how it connect with your data? why x is 35.2 and why y = 1.6? If apply your function to data, what happens? All data are changed or only some of them?

Comment: I said, that I have no duration of internet session in this data. This numbers it's time between every visit of url. `35.2 and 1.6` it's average values from other data. `35.2` - average time of session. `1.6` - average quantity visits of some browser

Comment: and for this data, that I specify if question, I should find to this time of session

Comment: I should get one average number to understand, how long is session

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 100
b = 33
df['diff_time'].apply(lambda el: b if el > a else el)

0     0
1    33
2    56
3    87
4    40
5    33
6    33
7    13
Name: diff_time, dtype: int64
```